# Chromium - how printing of text is done

Tags: c++, winapi, chromium

I'm browsing thought the source code of Chromium, and I don't see how a text from the current web page is getting printed - I see that Chromium uses EMF files for printing, but how the text from the printed page is added to the EMF file? (usually it would be though TextOut GDI call, but I don't see any reference to this call)